# Labview: element-wise array multiplication operations

Tags: arrays, matrix, element, multiplication, labview

Does there exist a function similar to that of numpy's `*` operator for two arrays to multiply their elements in an element-wise manner, returning an array of the similar type?

For example:

```
#Lets define:
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]
d = [[1,2] , [3,4], [5,6]]
e = [3,4,5]

#I want:
a * 2 == [2*0, 1*2, 2*2, 2*3]
a * b == [0*1, 1*2, 2*3, 3*4]
d * e == [[1*3, 2*3], [3*4, 4*4], [5*5, 6*5]]
d * d == [[1*1, 2*2], [3*3, 4*4], [5*5, 6*6]]
```

Note how `*`  IS NOT regular matrix multiplication it is element-wise multiplication.

My current best solution is to write some c code, which does this, and import a compiled dll.

There must exist a better solution.

EDIT:
Using LabVIEW 2011  - Needs to be fast.

Comment: what version of LabView?  Also, does this need to be (really) fast?

Comment: a*2, a*b will work with standard multiplication vi. For others you can create subvi that will have a ForLoop, you can also parallelize it to use multicore.

Comment: @BlacKow it 'works', but it performs proper matrix multiplication, not elementwise multiplication.

Comment: @BlacKow Implementation with for-loops in Labview is an order of magnitude slower than in C - where-as the pre-built operators on arrays and matrices are only slightly slower.

Comment: What's proper matrix multiplication for two vectors? Inner product? When multiplying two 1d arrays labview returns a 1d array with elements multiplicated

Comment: This is very strange, that ForLoop is order of magnitude slower. You sure you use indexing tunnels? And no array appending in your loop?

Comment: Could you check your I Want section. I spot two error (a*2, fourth element), and a*c, while c isn't defined.

Comment: I fixed the above mentioned errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first two multiplications can be done by using the 'multiply' primitive. Make sure the arrays in the second case are of the same length.
For the third multipllication you can use a for loop (with auto-indexing). This is needed because you need to instruct LabVIEW what the basic index is.
The last multiplication can (again) be done using  the multiply primitive.
[image]

Comment: Kudos to you for a working solution - but it appears that there does not exist a built in operator, and just for your reference - on my application this is 50 times slower than the C dll doing the same work.

Comment: Well 50 times is way too much. Can you run your benchmarks and upload both codesets (LabVIEW and C)?

Answer (score 0):

My result is different (opposite) from the previous posters. I generated a 4x1000 array of random numbers (magnitude 1000) which I multiplied by a 4x4 array of integers (1,2,3,4,...). I did this 100,000 times using the matrix multiplication VI and also using for loops to perform the operation on the arrays. I'm seeing times on the order of 0.328s for the matrix VIs and 0.051s for the for loops. Using a compiled DLL may be faster than Labview, but this does not seem to be true for the built-in functions.

This is certainly not what I expected, but it is consistent over many cycles. The VI is standard execution thread. All data types are set before the timed operations - no coercion takes place in the loops. The operations are performed separately, staged by a flat sequence structure, as is the time measurement. Parallelism is turned off.

Comment: Can you show us some code and narrow your answer to the question?